# Unable to install pyinstaller using the pip command

Tags: python, pip

Error output:

```
pip install pyinstaller
installing build dependencies 
Collecting wheel
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001BEF10AD0F0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/wheel/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001BEF10ADE48>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/wheel/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001BEF10BB518>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/wheel/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001BEF10BB320>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/wheel/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001BEF10BB7B8>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/wheel/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wheel (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for wheel
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `pip` is unable to connect to PyPI (where `pip` downloads Python packages from). Generally, you should ensure that:

- You have a working internet connection and `pip` is allowed to connect to external websites.
- `pip` is updated (`pip install -U pip`).

There may also (theoretically) be some issue with the certificates associated with `pip`/Python.

Note that you can manually download Python packages (often bundled as [`.whl` files](https://pythonwheels.com/) or `tar.gz` archives) and use `pip` to install them locally (e.g. `pip install pyinstaller-4.3.tar.gz`).

Be aware, however, that the most recent  versions of PyInstaller rely on a number of additional Python packages. These currently appear to include:

- [altgraph](https://pypi.org/project/altgraph/#files)
- [future](https://pypi.org/project/future/#files)
- [importlib-metadata](https://pypi.org/project/importlib-metadata/#files)
- [pefile](https://pypi.org/project/pefile/#files)
- [pyinstaller-hooks-contrib](https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller-hooks-contrib/#files)
- [pywin32-ctypes](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32-ctypes/#files)
- [setuptools](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/#files)
- [typing-extensions](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/#files)
- [zipp](https://pypi.org/project/zipp/#files)

---

**Resources**

- *[PyInstaller (PyPI)](https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/#files)*
- *[PyInstaller (Official Website)](https://www.pyinstaller.org/)*
- *[pip (PyPI)](https://pypi.org/project/pip/#files)*
- *[pip (Official Website)](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/)*